# onclick change class with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have an audio `font-awesome icon` which is generating in while loop something like this :

```
while(condition true) {
    <div class="ringtone-details-play-control">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i id="player_button" class="simple-player-play-control"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
}
```

Let us imagine that the while condition is true 5 times, then the audio control button will display 5 times.

Actually we want to add style `simple-player-stop-control` on onclick when an audio button is clicked.

So, I am doing with jquery something like this :

```
$('#player_button').click(function()) {
    $(this).toggleClass('simple-player-stop-control');
    $(this).toggleClass('simple-player-play-control');
}
```

but the problem is when i am clicking the first button then it works, but on the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th button is not working.

So help us how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The  problem is duplicate IDs. ID selector `$('#player_button')` is only targeting the first element.

IDs should be always unique. You should rather use same class say `player_button`

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <i class="player_button simple-player-play-control"></i>
 </a>
```

and then class selector to target them. also you can toggle 2 classes using single `.toggleClass`:

```
$('.player_button').click(function()) {
   $('.player_button').not(this).removeClass('simple-player-stop-control').addClass('simple-player-play-control');
   $(this).toggleClass('simple-player-play-control simple-player-stop-control');
}
```

**Update:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('button').not(this).removeClass('play-button').addClass(' stop-button');
  $(this).toggleClass('stop-button play-button');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsr6eryf/)**

Comment: one more problem is that if the class was changed, then after that if we click on another button the first is on same state. can we change that ?

Comment: @  Milind Anantwar  we wants when the another button will click then first button will stop, but in your updated answer when the another button is clicked then first going to be hide.

Comment: so should stop class be added to other elements??

Comment: @ Millind Anantwar when i am adding the stop to other elements, then when any first button is clicked then, except the first button all button is going to be hide.

Comment: @Rahul: can you create static fiddle with above scenario. Would make more sense.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link : [https:/jsfiddle.net/6hr6jb5d/] , actually in this i want to do is when the first button is clicked it's background color is going to be `blue` and afterthat if another button will clicked then the first button backgroundColor should be automatic converted to `green`.